# MDN Javascript geolocation API hardware dependencies

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation

This question is about the geolocation API by MDN. What type of hardware does this API use in order to determine a user's location? Is that GPS? Wifi network? Or cellular tower based trilateration?

From MDN documentation, this API has two methods that determine the user's location. They are
getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition(). Actually which method uses what hardware? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually android work two providers as you said GPS and network (including Wi-Fi and network). It will depend on your application permissions that the library uses one or another.

Supposing the permissions are activated for both sources, It will be receiving updates continuously from both sources and will try to keep the best location estimated. Usually, the GPS location will override the Wi-Fi and network location, so it will be used if possible.

So, when you call explicitly the library, it will return the best estimated location currently stored.

Comment: How to identify, which one is used exactly?

Comment: It will depends on your application permissions. If both permissions are set, all three strategies will be used to get the best possible location information